# jQuery mobile: position of paginational buttons

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have the following markup (and the resulting display shown below that).

I want the `Prev` and `Next` buttons to be placed closer to the left (as it is now) and the right edges of the bottom list divider respectively.

The middle button (this may be changed as a text) to be in the mid.

I tried almost all the usual technique such as `text-align:right` `right:5px` etc., but no success.

Can anyone suggest me a reliable cross browser way of doing this by CSS?

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider"> Cars</li>
                <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
                <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
                <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
                <li data-role="list-divider">

                    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-l">Prev</a>
                    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">1 of 2</a>
                    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Next</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
```

[image]

You can see a live example here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yyshf

Comment: Do you have a live example somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, still this work is in my localhost.:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, you can just float the anchors and add a margin to the two rightmost anchors:

http://jsfiddle.net/yyshf/1/

```
li.list-divider a
{
    float left;
}

li.list-divider a + a
{
    margin-left: 33%;
}
​
```

Remember that with jQuery mobile CSS you have to add your CSS to the bottom. You might also have to add classes to these anchors to more specifically select them, or it might mess something else up in your mobile site.

Comment: But in the output, the buttons (anchors) are not appearing in the same level?

Comment: In my example they are, are they not in your actual projecT?

Comment: I prefer 1st button on the left, 2nd in the mid and 3rd on the right, all in the same level – DUKE just now edit

Comment: That is exactly what my solution does. Change the margin % to suit your project. Which browser are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/yyshf/4/ here, just move the window size around to fix :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add to `<li data-role="list-divider"`> (which contains the buttons spans) the following style: `text-align: right;`

See http://jsfiddle.net/wF5qa/1/

Comment: But it technique shifts all the 3 buttons to the right. (I prefer 1st button on the left, 2nd in the mid and 3rd on the right)